# YAML related error during start of RStudio project in R

Tags: r, yaml, rstudio, r-markdown

I use an RStudio project to build an [R Markdown website](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/rmarkdown_websites.html). When I load the project, the following message arises in R console:

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) :   
    Reader error: control characters are not allowed: #8D at 41
```

When I used `rmarkdown::clean_site()`, the same error was displayed again.

I'd like to know what's the origin of this error and how to avoid it? Is it encoding-related (I use Lithuanian language and Lithuanian locale in `.Rmd` files)?

Comment: I guess so... You may identify guilty character by invoking from command line `enc2utf8` on pieces of strings within your yaml header. Note that I would recommend to use UTF-8 for `.Rmd`. If sticking to Lithunian is mandatory for you, I would try to knit document "manually" instead of using RStudio interface.